# How can i put my resources in the deployed WAR in a multi-module web project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, tomcat

Ok, so i have a multi-module web project (Spring, Hibernate and all that) consisting out of a WAR and 3 JARs. 2 of those JARs are optional extensions of the core WAR and JAR. The extentions are used by maven profiles which add them as dependencies or not. This all works fine.

However while installing the project on a Tomcat server i noticed i coulden't edit the property files of the extension modules since they are packaged in a JAR file. So i'm looking for a way to have my property files moved from my extension JAR to my deployable WAR's resources folder when i package my project using maven. This means that the resources will ONLY be in the WEB resources folder when the extension is activated.

How can i best do this?

**EDIT-01**

Ok so i've tried using the build-helper-maven-plugin which qza suggested.

test-war POM:

```
<project>
...    
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-resource</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>../extTestA-jar/src/main/resources</directory>
                                <targetPath>resources</targetPath>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

My project layout is as follows:

```
<Parent>
--><extTestA-jar>
--><extTestB-jar>
--><test-jar>
--><test-war>
```

With my resources in "src/main/resources"

Can anyone spot the problem in this? I've tried with and without the targetPath but none seem to work. I've also tried to do it at the generate-resources phase but still no luck. I was thinking the path could be wrong so i tried some others aswel but still no luck.

Comment: If you're intending to edit the property files _in place_ in the Tomcat server then externalizing them out of webapp entirely would be the way to go here (as Mustafa Genc describes). If they are inside the webapp, then they will potentially get overwritten when a new release is deployed to Tomcat.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at it and came to the same conclusion. However since overwriting is not realy a problem, my boss wanted it in the WAR resource folder. So i went with the suggestion of qza.

That said, Mustafa's answer is the better one if both choices are open to you. However i'm limited by the wishes of my boss. So can anyone spot the problem in my code?

Comment: Here is a small demo to show how to copy resources https://github.com/qza/maven-examples

Comment: Ok thanks man! I got it to work. Add-resources didn't work because of some freaky error where i had to add the pluginManager tag. So i got both of them working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use [Maven Build Helper Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) and executing goal:

> add-resources

Complete example would be:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>add-resources</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>add-resource</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>../data-module/src/main/resources</directory>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Another way would be to use [Maven Resources Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/plugin-info.html) and goal

> copy-resources

For this plugin, usage goes simillar to this:

```
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>copy-resources</id>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>../data-module/src/main/resources</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Both plugins can help with tasks like this one.

Comment: The add-resources looks promising. Will try it. Thanks. Will post the results when i'm finished.

Comment: Ok so i've tried the add-resource but i can't seem to get it to work. I'm getting no errors but it doesn't seem to do anything. I've updated my original post with my changes and the things i've tried. Do you see a problem?

Comment: Build log shows execution of the add resource goal. There could be an info like "skip non existing resource Directory" or some other error message

Answer (score 1):

It's better to read properties from outside the project. Create a configuration folder for your application server and define it in server start script such as:

```
-Dconfiguration.dir=/etc/tomcatConf
```

Then put your configuration files/folder under that folder and scan those with spring property placeholder bean:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:${configuration.dir}/module1/auth.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, when you change a property, you will need to only restart the server, no recreation of war/jard is needed.

Note that you don't need to have a system argument. It's for keeping a standart configuration directory for your application server. You can just use:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>file:/etc/conf/auth.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```